# How to map Set<String>?

Tags: grails, elasticsearch

My Grails domain class is backed by mongodb and tags property:

```
   Set<String> tags
```

I'm trying to make it searchable and can be queried by "tags:something,somethingelse".

Answer (score 0):

Let me quote a bit adapted example from [Understanding MongoDB Querying in Grails and GORM](http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2013/05/28/understanding-mongodb-querying-in-grails-and-gorm/)

> For collections of non-objects such as List, the inList function in
>   Grails can check for the specific existence of an item.

```
YourDomainClass.findAll {
    inList('tags', 'something', 'somethingelse')
}
```

> This produces the MongoDB query { tags: { $in: [ "something", "somethingelse" ] } } correlating to the $in operator.

So I believe it's only matter of proper query with GORM.